# jQuery $('img[alt]') vs. $('img').attr('alt')?

Tags: jquery, image, get, alt

Two parts to my question.
Just something I keep wondering about.

1) What is the difference between using:

```
$('img[alt]').get(-1); // ignore the .get
```

vs

```
$('img').attr('alt').get(-1); // ignore the .get
```

Is the first option a valid way of accessing the `alt` attribute of an image? Or is only the second valid?

and 2) Is it even valid to have a number (negative or not) as an argument inside a .get request? I'm positive it's not but I want to be sure... Thanks!

Comment: The second one isn't valid with `.get()`. `.attr()` returns a string, but `.get()` is a method of jQuery objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are different. The first option does not get the `alt` attribute, whereas the second one does.

- `$('img[alt]')` - The selector `img[alt]` will select an `img` element with an `alt` attribute. It's worth mentioning that `[alt]` is an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

  In other words, based on the selector `img[alt]`:

  ```
  <!-- This img element would be selected because it *has* an 'alt' attribute. -->
  <img src="../" alt="Alt attribute" />

  <!-- This img element would NOT be selected. -->
  <img src="../" />
  ```
- `$('img').attr('alt')` - The [`.attr()` method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) will either get or set the attribute of the selected element(s). So in this case, `$('img').attr('alt')` will *retrieve* the `alt` attribute of the `img` element.

---

The [`.get()` method](https://api.jquery.com/get/#get-index) will retrieve the DOM element(s) matched by the jQuery selectors. The only parameters this method accepts is the index of the element you want to get. This parameter is optional, and an index of `-1` won't return an element.

---

As a side note, you can't chain the `.get()` method *after* the `.attr()` method.